# PDO returning error "could not find driver" with a known working DSN

Tags: php, pdo, odbc, dsn

I'm trying to connect to an odbc database via php's `PDO` class:

```
$dsn = 'odbc:CS_HDZipCodes32bit';
$username = 'demo';
$password = 'skdemo!';

$connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);

die( var_dump( $connection ) );
```

but when I do, I get the error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\pdoClass.php:7 Stack trace: #0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\pdoClass.php(7): PDO->__construct('odbc:CS_HDZipCo...', 'demo', 'skdemo!') #1 {main} thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\pdoClass.php on line 7

The `$dsn` value is the name of the DSN I created in my ODBC Manager.

[image: odbc manager's dsns]

I know this particular DSN works because I was able to build another demo file and connect successfully via `odbc_connect`:

```
$connection = odbc_connect("CS_HDZipCodes32bit", 'demo', 'skdemo!');

if(!$connection){
    die('connection failed');
}

$statement = "SELECT * FROM ZipCodes";

$result = odbc_exec($connection, $statement);


// Outputs the zips as expected
var_dump(odbc_result_all($result));
```

I've been digging through the [PDO-ODBC](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.connection.php) documentation as well as other resources online, but I can't figure out why PHP is unable to find the driver when trying from PDO.

Any ideas?

## Update

I popped open my phpinfo page to make sure the odbc driver is installed per Marc B's comment:

[image: odbc in phpini]

It looks like the driver is installed unless this is a different driver.

## Another Update

On further inspection of my phpini per Marc B's additional comment, it looks like I don't have the POD ODBC specific driver installed:

[image]

So here, if I had the ODBC driver for pdo installed, `odbc` would be at the end of the list, correct?

Comment: did you try odbc_connect on your "bad" dsn?

Comment: Yes, the code block at the bottom was me using the same dsn from the top with odbc_connect.

Comment: ok, then did you check if the pdo odbc driver is installed? pdo has its own drivers, and doesn't just "wrap" `odbc_*()` functions.

Comment: It looks like I do. I updated the original question with a screen shot showing the phpinfo's odbc section.

Comment: that's odbc itself, but not pdo odbc. they're two completely separate DB interfaces. That's your `odbc_connect()` is functioning, but has absolutely nothing to do with pdo.

Comment: Ahhh ok I see what you mean. I'm posting another screen shot. I think you sent me in the right direction.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After getting some great help from Marc B in the initial question's comments it turns out the problem was coming from my misunderstanding of enabling `odbc` on my web server and having the `pdo_odbc` driver installed.

While I did have odbc enabled on the web server, I did not have the odbc driver installed for PDO.

[image: missing odbc driver]

This driver is necessary to be able to access odbc databases via pdo.

Per the php.net documentation on [installing pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php) for windows, the driver was already included in the php build (I'm using version 5.5) and just needed to be included in the `php.ini` file.

[image: including php_pdo.dll]

After adding the driver and restarting the server I now had the driver loaded:

[image]

and my test query using PDO on my demo database worked:

```
$dsn = 'odbc:CS_HDZipCodes32bit';
$username = 'demo';
$password = 'skdemo!';

$connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);

$query = "Select * FROM ZipCodes";


$result = $connection->query($query);

foreach($result as $row){
    var_dump($row);
}
```

Dumps out:

[image: pdo var dump]

Thanks for your help Marc B.

Comment: Especially for Windows, If you are absolutely sure your `php.ini` has settings that should enable your extensions, check `phpinfo()` for where it has loaded the `php.ini`. In my case, it was still looking in `C:\Windows` and I forgot to at least at an httpd `PHPINIDir` directive to tell it the exactly location.