# What are the compatible versions of PHP and SQLSRV driver for SQL Server 2000?

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I'm using the following:

PHP = 7.0.18
pdo_sqlsrv = 4.2.0-preview+9718

and I need to connect it to SQL server 2000. I tried it with 2008 and it worked.

My error with 2000:

Connection error: SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server does not support connections to SQL Server 2000 or earlier versions.

Comment: Is it compatible with the SS 2000 ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver take look at this

Comment: Its not there. i searched on google on this and the lowest version of php for sqlsrv is 2005. i guess. haven't tried tho

Comment: I followed the answer to the link below and it worked! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31813574/pdo-returning-error-could-not-find-driver-with-a-known-working-dsn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None - see here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver

mostly because you are using php 7 which limits available the drivers.

You can try to access it thru ODBC or you can try to link then 2000 server into the 2008 server.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine

Update:
i was focused on headline. 
SQLSRV <> PDO !

You can use PDO_ODBC in this case.
PDO_MSSQL can't be used because i needs SQLSRV version 2 or 3 - because of PHP7 you can only use version 4.

http://php.net/manual/de/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php