# Can't connect to odbc in php. could not find drivers

Tags: php, odbc, sybase

im trying to connect to a database on odbc with php and i get the error of

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in C:\xampp\htdocs\testarsybase\index.php:3 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\testarsybase\index.php(3): PDO->__construct('odbc:host=192.1...', 'sa', '') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\testarsybase\index.php on line 3

im using the `PDO('odbc (..)')` to connect

What should i do?

Comment: 1. Provide your complete PDO call, so we can see what might be wrong with it. 2. Take a look at the [PHP PDO docs](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). 3. Also try to [ask a better question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), so we can provide better answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDO returning error "could not find driver" with a known working DSN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31813574/pdo-returning-error-could-not-find-driver-with-a-known-working-dsn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this situation helps you. It seems to be the same question.

[PDO returning error “could not find driver” with a known working DSN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31813574/pdo-returning-error-could-not-find-driver-with-a-known-working-dsn)